# Div overlap not correct

Tags: css, html, overlap

I'm having a problem with making one `div` overlap the rest of the page.

I just need one image to overlap one section. I have kinda got it to work but once you resize the window or look at it on a different resolution the image doesn't appear where it should.

I'm using an `position:absolute;` and z-index. It is working to some extent. but it won't stay in that position, for example, if you resize your browser window (it moves from where I'd like it to stay).

Here is [this website](http://www.impactfitness.me.uk/star/layout.htm)

I need it to overlap the [yellow box like this](http://www.impactfitness.me.uk/star/medaloverlay.jpg).

**Edit:** Just a quick follow up: I think your solution has put me a bit of bother. I am unable to place another `div` directly under it [as can be seen here](http://impactfitness.me.uk/star/layout.htm)

Comment: have you tried position:fixed instead of position:absolute?

Comment: I have tried this still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
<div id="medal"><img src="images/star2012medal.png" width="220" height="277"></div>
```

inside

```
<div id="box"><img src="images/boxheading.png"></div>
```

just before the image.

Change the `CSS` to

```
#medal {
    position: relative;
    top: -240px;
    right: -80px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

and apply the following to the `boxheading.png` image

```
{
    position: relative;
    top: -280px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

*From what I feel you are trying to achieve, you should be looking at a 2-column layout. There's too many good-practice resources online to learn how to do it.*

To add another box below the first one, you will need to do the following changes to `html`:

```
<div id="box-container">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="medal">
            <img src="images/star2012medal.png" width="220" height="277">
        </div>
        <img src="images/boxheading.png" width="291px" height="240px" style="position: relative; top: -280px; ">
    </div>
    <div id="box2">testing</div>
</div>
```

then add the following `css`:

```
#box-container {
    float: right;
}

#box {
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    height: 240px;
    width: 291px;
    display: inline;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff100;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    clear: both;
}

#box2 {
    float: left;
    color: #333;
    background: #fff;
    height: 240px;
    width: 291px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff100;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

*tested only in Chrome. Remember to test it in other browsers!*

Comment: ok ignore this answer for some time. getting back with a better one!

Comment: Thanks for the reply just tried what you have suggested but hasn't worked

Comment: thank you so much for the help I have been stuck on this for hours! Greatly appreciate the help

Comment: glad it helped and thanks for the accept!! 8) could you also upvote the answer, as it would give me some points too :)

Comment: just a quick follow up i think your solution has put me a bit of bother I am unable to place another div directly under it as can be seen below

http://www.impactfitness.me.uk/star/layout.htm

coding is frustrating sometimes!

Comment: Could you add this as an `edit` to your question for completeness. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you again for the help and in the future I will take the two-column approach.